# php select users not found in another table when the values in that table are blank

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query that is supposed to look through the rota table and select the idstaff an then find all users that are not currently found in that result.  As long as idstaff is not null this query works fine however there are cases where idstaff will be NULL.  In this case the query fails.  Is there any way I can make it work in both instances?

```
   $query = sprintf("SELECT user.*
    FROM user 
    WHERE user.iduser NOT IN (SELECT idstaff FROM rota WHERE idrota=%s)",
    $this->db->GetSQLValueString($idrota, "int"));
    $result = $this->db->query($this->db->link, $query) or die($this->db->error($this->db->link));
```

Comment: a ternary operator or an `OR` operator could work

Comment: @Fred-ii- please could you explain what you mean a bit further? thank you

Comment: Ternary http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php example: `echo (true?'true':false?'t':'f');` or `WHERE x = y OR x IS NOT NULL` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/working-with-null.html

Comment: This `... WHERE idrota = %s AND idstaff <> NULL)", ...`, may be?

Comment: @RajdeepPaul thank you for being a little clearer.  Your solution worked.  Please write your answer up so I can accept it.

Comment: so my `OR` should have been an `AND` *lol* oh well, I wasn't far off ;-) you could have worked it a bit though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken straight from my comment, your query string should be like this:

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT user.*
FROM user 
WHERE user.iduser NOT IN (SELECT idstaff FROM rota WHERE idrota=%s AND idstaff <> NULL)",
$this->db->GetSQLValueString($idrota, "int"));
```

Comment: Good stuff Rajdeep. However, the example I gave the OP... well TBH, they could have worked it a bit ;-) You give them examples as a means for them to think about it so they'll actually learn from it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- sometimes seeing is learning. I now wont make that mistake again.

Comment: Thanks @Fred-ii-, I sincerely appreciate your thought. Cheers! :-)

Comment: @DanielRobinson Agreed. I'm the type of person who'll be given something to fix, for instance a small engine (I work in mechanics too). If a part doesn't seem to fit one way because it wasn't properly outlined in the manual it came with, I'll alter it / make it work till it does ;-) Kind of like MacGyver.

Answer (score -1):

You should add NULL because sql skips these records by default.

$query = sprintf("SELECT user.*
    FROM user 
    WHERE user.iduser IS NULL OR NOT IN (SELECT idstaff FROM rota WHERE idrota=%s)",
    $this->db->GetSQLValueString($idrota, "int"));
    $result = $this->db->query($this->db->link, $query) or die($this->db->error($this->db->link));